# split a string parts in complex string

Tags: java

```
String string = "[A100, test, message1, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38],
[A101, test, message2, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38],
[A102, test, message3, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38],
[A103, test, message4, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38]"

I want split as four parts
A101, test, message2, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
A101, test, message2, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
A102, test, message3, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
A103, test, message4, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
```

can you please do as soon as possible.

```
List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(incomingString.split("],"));
        for (String string1 : elephantList) {
            if(string1.contains("Intro to Working with the IACUC") ||string1.contains("Working with the IACUC")){
```

Comment: _can you please do as soon as possible_ Welcome to `SO`. Please describe your code and explain the problem youre having

Comment: Please fix your formatting, specify your question, and as you do not pay anybody here, we do nothing "as soon as possible".

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps u :

```
String string = "[A100, test, message1, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38],[A101, test, message2, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38], [A102, test, message3, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38],[A103, test, message4, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38]";

String [] s1=string.split("\\],");
for(String s : s1)
{
 System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[ \\[\\]  ]", ""));
}
```

Output:

```
A100, test, message1, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
A101, test, message2, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
A102, test, message3, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
A103, test, message4, 6/24/2015 19:38, 6/24/2015 19:38
```